# Receiving an error when trying to install my android application

Tags: python, android, parsing, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to create a simple "Hello World" application for android using Kivy in Python but I'm receiving an error when i try to install the application on my phone.

The error is:
"There was a problem parsing the package"

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This is the YouTube tutorial that i followed to create my APK file:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr7n0C2tspI

Comment: Please provide the full error

Comment: Please share the error stack along with your codebase

Comment: @Sujay How do i do that?
I only get the parsing error my android phone is showing me when i try to install the app

Comment: @Alok Raj I don't know how to do that, should i post the code i compiled into the APK file?

Comment: You are not getting any error while compiling it on the local emulator? Did you compare the android version that the tutorial is using? Please do that. And try running this on the local emulator and see the error you are getting. If still, you have doubt, please reach out to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i didn't follow the YouTube video exactly,
Instead of uploading the APK file to a google drive/onedrive i transferred it manually through a cable to my phone.

I think that doing it manually corrupts the file or something because i tried doing it through google drive and it works!